# How to access files in Virtualbox Ubuntu when in Window 10 due to failure of booting up ubuntu

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I have installed both Virtualbox and Ubuntu in Window 10. Ubuntu work properly in Virtualbox. I can run the command in Ubuntu and stored the files in the Ubuntu. However, recently I tried to run Ubuntu in VirtualBox, I get stuck in the entering Ubuntu.

After seeing this screen, the whole screen is black out

[please click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX8IZ.jpg)
[Press F12 during boot up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGL5q.jpg)
[DEPEND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvIQ8.jpg)
[ISO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBCsJ.jpg)
All my files are in Ubuntu directory not in shared folder with Window. May I know if there is any way to access the files that have been stored in Ubuntu and transfer back to Window 10. Or how to solve the booting problem so that I can enter Ubuntu and rescue the files?

Comment: Try booting from ubuntu iso file instead of the virtual disk. I suppose you can access the boot menu by pressing F12. And before that, add the iso file in storage settings. You should be able to access the files on Ubuntu virtual disk.

Comment: Hi Mido, do you mean in VirtualBox Manager ->Settings ->/Storage-> under Storage Devices, select VBoxGuestAdditions.iso. And when booting the Ubuntu,  I have pressed F12 . I see a lot of [OK]. However, there have some items with [DEPEND]. I am not sure whether these are the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have screen capture two images during the boot up and put inside the post. Would you please have a look and see the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I mean the iso you used to install Ubuntu not the guest additions one. When you run the live cd you'd be able to access your files by simply using a file manager. And copy those files to an accessible directory. As Windows won't be able to access Ubuntu files

Comment: Would you please explain more detail on how to access the files on Ubuntu virtual disk? as

Comment: Mido, I have added the screen capture image of the ISO in the post. This is the one that I used to install Ubuntu. I don't have live CD.

Comment: Live CD is the same as "Try Ubuntu without installing"

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit the settings of Ubuntu virtual machine.
2. Go to storage and add Ubuntu iso file. (for example ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)
3. Start the virtual machine and boot from CD by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and then press <kbd>C</kbd>

Once Ubuntu starts open **Files**. You should be able to access your files now.

You can use a flash drive but you need to shut down the virtual machine and install [VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) for virtualbox version installed  on your computer.
And then enable usb controller in virtual machine settings.

start the virtual machine

Add the flash drive to the virtual machine to copy your files

Comment: You might mention that this is an easy but temporary solution to recover files.

Comment: Thanks Mido. I can get into Ubuntu through "Try Ubuntu". I go into file Manager.

Comment: @user535733 Exactly. OP can reinstall Ubuntu on virtualbox after backing up the needed files.

Comment: However, my files are put under my account (I need to log in). How can I log in my account to access the files? Now I am at the stage of "ubuntu@ubuntu".

Comment: @pythonbeginner You just need to look for "Home" directory where your files reside.

Comment: no files present

Comment: my files are at my account sandra@sandra

Comment: @pythonbeginner is your data stored on cloud?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: does it mean there is no hope in getting back the files?

Comment: @pythonbeginner open files > other locations > look for a folder named home > look for a folder with your username. Can you see your files ? (the home folder where Ubuntu is installed not the iso you are using)

Comment: Mido, I found my files. Thank you so much. May I know how can I transfer the files back to Window? I am really new in using Ubuntu and VirtualBox

Comment: @pythonbeginner I edited my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. At the moment, I mount my email account in ubuntu and transfer some of the important files to the cloud of the email account (due to limited space). I will try your method tmr as it is now 4am midnight. I really appreciate your help and thank you.

Comment: Mido, I have successfully download all my files in Ubuntu to flash drive. Thank you very much.

Comment: @pythonbeginner You're welcome. I'm glad my answer is helpful